# Python: custom deepcopy in class hierarchy

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class hierarchy representing linear algebra expression (as expression trees), something like this (it’s actually more complicated than that, but that should be enough to give you an idea).

- Expression

  - Operator

    - Times
    - Plus
  - Symbol

    - Matrix
    - Scalar

I’m manipulating those expression in many different ways, so I have to copy those expression a lot because I want to explore different ways of manipulating them (I really don’t see any way around copying them). Not surprisingly, `copy.deepcopy()` is slow.

Not all class attributes need do be deepcopied, and those expression trees will always be trees (if not, something is fundamentally wrong), so I can probably save some time by simplifying the memoization (or don’t use it at all).

I want to make copying faster by implementing a custom copy function. This could either mean implementing `__deepcopy__()`, writing an entirely new function or using something like `get_state` and `set_state`, I really don’t care. At the moment, I don’t care about pickling.

I’m using Python 3.

Since I have this class hierarchy where new attributes are introduced at different levels, I would prefer not to start from scratch on each level. Instead, it would be desirable to reuse some functionality of the superclass similar to how in `__init__`, one usually calls `__init__` of the superclass. However, I would prefer not to call `__init__` because that sometimes does some extra stuff that is not necessary when copying.

How do I do that in the fastest and most pythonic way? I was not able to find any reasonable guidelines regarding how to implement this copy functionality under those circumstances. I looked at the implementation of deepcopy both in Python 2 and 3. In Python 2, a bunch of different methods are used (`get_state`/`set_state`, using `__dict__`,…), in Python 3, I’m not able to find the corresponding function at all.

Answer (score 2):

I found one possible solution myself:

```
class Expression(object):
    ...
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        cpy = object.__new__(type(self))
        # manually copy all attributes of Expression here
        return cpy

class Operator(Expression):
    ...
    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        cpy = Expression.__deepcopy__(self, memo)
        # manually copy all attributes exclusive to Operator here
        return cpy
```

The new object is always created in `__deepcopy__` of `Expression`. By using `object.__new__(type(self))`, the new object has the type of the object on which `__deepcopy__` was originally called (for example `Operator`).

Unfortunately, this solution is not much faster than the default deepcopy. I'm wondering if this is because of all those calls to `__deepcopy__` all the way to the top of the class hierarchy. I will investigate this.